# I'm trying to print a webpage containing js charts but the converted document contains everything except those charts

Tags: php, chart.js

I'm trying to generate a pdf from a webpage containing js charts but the converted document contains everything except those charts. Please help me.

**Webpage**

[image: This is the webpage]

**Printpage**

[image: This is the print page]

Comment: Are you sure you succesfully loaded the full chart before printing it ? Some elements of Chart.js aren't loaded immediatly if there's an animation for instance.

Comment: Yes. In web page there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export canvas to base64 image and replace chart with it on printing page - 
[Chart.js Issues](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/99)